# $a_{n+1}=\frac1{a_n}+\frac{a_n}2,$ prove that the sequence is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, induction, recurrence-relations

Let
$$a_1=2\quad\text{and}\quad a_{n+1}=\frac1{a_n}+\frac{a_n}2\quad(\forall n\ge1).$$

i)Show that the sequence (a_n) is bounded

ii) Show that (a_n) is decreasing

What i've tried:
i) Most likely going to be via induction? I've tried setting my claim as 1<a_n<=2 , but can't seem to get anywhere with it.

ii) a_n+1-a_n = 1/a_n -a_n/2 . Now need to show that this is <0 but can't see a way to do this without having bounds from (i)

thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real infinite sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790386/real-infinite-sequence) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba_n%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%7D%7B2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_1%3D2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Abounded%2C%20OR%20content%3Adecreasing&p=1). In particular, the currently accepted [answer](/a/2790415) there shows the sequence bounded below by $\sqrt{2}$ and is non-increasing. Note there are other basically duplicate questions found, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} v_{n+1} = \sqrt{2}$?](/q/2338396) and [Proving the limit of a recursive sequence](/q/948452). Also, there're questions with a starting value of $a_1=1$ instead at [How to prove the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}2 + \frac 1{x_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence](/q/930484) & [Prove that $\{x_1=1,\,x_{n+1}=\frac {x_n}2+\frac 1{x_n} \}$ converges when $n \to \infty$](/q/416274). Finally, there's the related AoPS thread of [for which values this succession converges?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1700432p10921588) (re: valid starting values).

Comment: It helps a lot, however currently i only have a lower bound for a_n, i need to show its bounded above and below. With the lower bound part ii comes immediately so it's just finding this last bit

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I'm glad you found those other posts to be helpful. Also, note proving the sequence is non-increasing automatically means it's bounded above by $a_1=2$.

Comment: Yes you're right, not sure how i didn't spot that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $a_n>0$ implies $a_{n+1}>0$. Since $a_1=2>0$, $a_n>0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

To prove $a_n$ is decreasing, observe $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2}<0 \iff a_n^2>2.$$

We study when $a_{n+1}^2>2$: $$a_{n+1}^2=\frac{1}{a_n^2}+\frac{a_n^2}{4}+1>2\iff 4+a_n^4>4a_n^2\iff (a_n^2-2)^2>0\iff a_n^2\ne2$$

$a_1^2=4>2$, hence $a_n^2>2$, $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, so $a_n$ is strictly decreasing. It follows that $a_n\le a_1=2$, so $0<a_n\le2$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nonstandard approach, but I include it as a curiosity:

A closed form representation for your function can be written in the form $x \mapsto \sqrt{2} \coth(m_xc)$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is a constant and $m_x$ is increasing as $x$ increases. Since the hyperbolic cotangent is a decreasing function for $x>0$ and bounded below by $1$, parts (ii) and (i) of your question both follow. In particular, your terms are strictly decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt{2}$.

[**Here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vmeol9afuk) is a graph in Desmos:

[image]